# simulate a while loop using for loop using jstl

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, for-loop, iterator, jstl

I have this piece of code as below

```
     while(children.hasNext())
            {
                Page child1=children.next();
            }
```

I need to have this code in my jstl using for loop or for each loop.

May I know how we can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `<c:forEach>` tag in the core JSTL library. It is one of the most useful and versatile tag, being used whenever it is necessary to iterate over data.

```
<c:forEach var="listObject" items="${myForm.myList}">
    <c:out value="${listObject.name}" />
</c:forEach>
```

**P.S:** Do not forget to add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` to your `JSP`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,in that while loop i have one statement Page child1=children.next();how to do this in that foreach statement and also do we need exit explicitly from foreach loop and if so how to do that

Comment: you needn't do the `hasNext()` or `next()`. `forEach` will handle that. It'll iterate over that `list`, till there are elements, and keep doing next by itself.

Comment: ok ok, one last question please,how to store ${listObject.name} in a jsp variable

Comment: `<c:set var="i" value="${listObject.name}"/>`

Comment: ya ok, Thanks for your help R.J